# Update one item of an array which is a property of an object in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I'm trying to update an single item of an array in mongodb with nodejs. My data structure in mongodb is something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5e818db59cedd232d83c66cb",
    "project": "projectX",
    "version": 1,
    "salesChannel": "channel42",
    "country": "Austria",
    "book": true,
    "categories": [
      {
        "pieceItems": [
          {
            "category": "pieceItems",
            "identifier": "1.1",
            "registrationHints": "Scan the barcode OR register the itemNumber manually",
            "variant": "Tax-Group 19%",
            "additionalHints": "optionally provided"
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        "weightItems": [
          {
            "category": "weightItems",
            "identifier": "2.1",
            "registrationHints": "Scan the barcode OR register the itemNumber manually",
            "variant": "Tax-Group 19%",
            "additionalHints": "optionally provided"
          },
          {
            "category": "weightItems",
            "identifier": "2.2",
            "registrationHints": "Scan the barcode OR register the itemNumber manually",
            "variant": "Tax-Group 19%",
            "additionalHints": "optionally provided"
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
}
```

This is the code with I tryed but nothing changes in my database:

```
exports.editCategoryInBook = function (body, project, salesChannelName, country) {
  mongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, async (err, client) => {
    assert.equal(null, err)
    const db = client.db(dbName)
    var categoryName = Object.keys(body)[0]
    var updateCategory = `categories.$.${categoryName}`
    var categoryValue = body[categoryName]
    console.log(`$set: { ${updateCategory}: categoryValue }`)
    db.collection(project).updateOne({
      "book": true,
      "salesChannel": salesChannelName,
      "country": country
    }, {
      $set: { [updateCategory]: categoryValue },
      $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
    })
    client.close()
  })
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve();
  });
}
```

This is the body variable which is passed to the function:

```
{
    "pieceItems": [
    {
        "category": "Piece Item",
        "identifier": 1.11,
        "registrationHints": "Scan the barcode OR register the itemNumber manually; some more hints could follow",
        "variant": "Tax-Group 19%",
        "additionalHints": "some string hint to give bonus information about this item",
        "name": "Buntsteinputz 8508",
        "EAN": 4003498690070,
        "PLU": 3822584,
        "price": "51,95€"
    },
    {
        "category": "Piece Item",
        "identifier": 1.2,
        "registrationHints": "Scan the barcode OR register the itemNumber manually; some more hints could follow",
        "variant": "Tax-Group 7%",
        "additionalHints": "some string hint to give bonus information about this item",
        "name": "Buntsteinputz 8508",
        "EAN": 4003498690070,
        "PLU": 3822584,
        "price": "51,95€"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the following output from the console.log:

```
$set: { categories.$.pieceItems: categoryValue }
```

And I get the following Error:

```
MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
at Function.create (C:\Users\rkrause\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\error.js:43:12)
at toError (C:\Users\rkrause\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:149:22)
at C:\Users\rkrause\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:376:39
at C:\Users\rkrause\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:404:18
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9)
```

Comment: What's the reason for using `"param": true`?

Comment: @Ramesh ohhh thank you! I forgot to change it to `"book": true` and updated an other file.. that was the mistake

Comment: Glad I'm helpful. Everyone does these silly mistakes and only others can spot them because they go line by line and we don't do that when we check our own code :).

Comment: Do you want to _add additional fields_ (EAN, PLU, price)  to the existing sub-documents within the `pieceItems` array.

Comment: @prasad_ yes I want to update the whole pieceItems Array if there are differences to the body

Comment: What do you mean by: _"... if there are differences to the body"_. Please reply to my previous comment correctly.

Comment: sry I gave u not enough context. with body I meant the datastructure in my question. So I mean the new value

Comment: It will clear if you update your post with correct updated output. The input document has _one_ element for the `pieceItems` array. The output shows _two_ elements. Please correct that, so that I can try to get you a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now the problem is, that it doesn't want to update all the things in it unless it matches some search query in the filter part. But i think we can trick it into doing that like:

```js
const WhatToSet = `categories.$.${categoryName}`


db.collection(project).updateOne({
  "book": true,
  "salesChannel": salesChannelName,
  "country": country,
  [`categories.${categoryName}`]: {$exists: true}
}, {
  $set: { [WhatToSet]: categoryValue },
  $currentDate: { lastModified: true }
})
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, i think u lead me into the right direction. I've updated my question, could u please review my changes?

Comment: Maybe it needs to be like 'categories.$.pieceItems' but that would be a cyntax error i think.

Comment: I updated the answer. I think we can trick mongo into doing the thing :D

Comment: perfect, thank you so much! I will accept your answer. Please set `\`categories.${categoryName}\``and `WhatToSet` into sqaure brackets, because it doesn't work without.

Comment: I'm not sure I edited it correctly, nor do I understand why would that make sence. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `[\`categories.${categoryName}\`]` this is the correct way. If u miss the square , then `categories.${categoryName}` is written as string and not as variable

Comment: Yeah that makes sense